# Getting summary values from other dataset up to some date value for each observation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I currently have two datasets. The first one has weekly observations for each ID (the number of weeks observed may not be the same across different IDs, but all are within a fixed range, the year of 2022):

| ID | Date | Var1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-04 | 200 |
| 1 | 2022-07-11 | 45 |
| 1 | 2022-07-18 | 70 |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 | 90 |
| 2 | 2022-06-27 | 50 |
| 2 | 2022-07-18 | 70 |
| 2 | 2022-08-01 | 90 |
| 3 | 2022-09-26 | 70 |
| 3 | 2022-10-03 | 90 |

The second one has the same IDs, but with values recorded not according to some fixed interval (i.e. can be any date and number of observations)

| ID | Date | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-12-06 | 200 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 2022-07-29 | 300 | 0.6 |
| 2 | 2015-06-27 | 100 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 2016-07-04 | 150 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 2016-07-05 | 200 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 2018-09-21 | 600 | 0.0 |

My goal is to include in the first dataset summaries of Var2 and Var3 from the second dataset UP TO the value specified in Date (i.e. the average of all values of Var2 and Var3 prior to Date). The desired output would be:

| ID | Date | Var1 | Mean_Var2 | Mean_Var3 | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-04 | 200 | 200 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-07-11 | 45 | 200 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-07-18 | 70 | 200 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 | 90 | 250 | 0.55 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-06-27 | 50 | 262.5 | 0.15 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-07-18 | 70 | 262.5 | 0.15 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-08-01 | 90 | 262.5 | 0.15 | 4 |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 | 70 | NA | NA | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-12-03 | 90 | NA | NA | 0 |

where `N` contains a count of the values which were averaged.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                  Date = as.Date(c('2022-07-04', '2022-07-11', '2022-07-18', '2022-08-01',
                                   '2022-06-27', '2022-07-18', '2022-08-01',
                                   '2022-12-01', '2022-12-03')),
                  Var1 = c(200, 45, 70, 90, 50, 70, 90, 70, 90))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  Date = as.Date(c('2010-12-06', '2022-07-29', 
                                   '2015-06-27', '2016-07-04', '2016-07-05', '2018-09-21')),
                  Var2 = c(200, 300, 100, 150, 200, 600),
                  Var3 = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.0))
```

I am a bit stumped as to how to go about this. I was thinking of just iterating by row across the first dataset and constructing the measure for each row, but the datasets themselves are also quite large ( > 1 million obs each), so this seems inefficient. Does anyone know a faster way?

Comment: Most of the "weekly" `df1` dates are Monday, but the last two aren't, are they supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join by `ID` in all cases where the `Date` in `df2` is less than the `Date` in `df1`. Sounds like a case for the `data.table` [non-equi join](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table.express/vignettes/joins.html)!

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[, date_for_join_df2 := Date]

df2[df1,
    on = .(
        ID,
        date_for_join_df2 < Date
    )
][, .(
        ID, 
        Date = date_for_join_df2, 
        Mean_Var2 = mean(Var2),
        Mean_Var3 = mean(Var3),
        .N
    )
, by = .(ID, date_for_join_df2)
]


#    ID date_for_join_df2 ID       Date Mean_Var2 Mean_Var3 N
# 1:  1        2022-07-04  1 2022-07-04     200.0      0.50 1
# 2:  1        2022-07-11  1 2022-07-11     200.0      0.50 1
# 3:  1        2022-07-18  1 2022-07-18     200.0      0.50 1
# 4:  1        2022-08-01  1 2022-08-01     250.0      0.55 2
# 5:  2        2022-06-27  2 2022-06-27     262.5      0.15 4
# 6:  2        2022-07-18  2 2022-07-18     262.5      0.15 4
# 7:  2        2022-08-01  2 2022-08-01     262.5      0.15 4
# 8:  3        2022-12-01  3 2022-12-01        NA        NA 1
# 9:  3        2022-12-03  3 2022-12-03        NA        NA 1
```

Thanks to the magic of `data.table` this should be quite fast. Note the `df2[, date_for_join_df2 := Date]`. It's important to copy the column and join on that as you lose one of the columns you join on - which is fine with an `equi` join, but not when it's not equal to the column it has joined to.

I linked to the `data.table` vignette above. This [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins/) by David Selby contains a more in-depth explanation and examples.

Comment: I wonder if it might be faster to pre-compute on `df2` the rolling average up to that date per group, and then join on that. But it sounds like this is plenty fast already.

Comment: @JonSpring do you think it would be? I've tended to find that grouped averages are very fast in `data.table` and rolling averages are not quite as fast. Impossible to know about this case without benchmarking. But does your experience differ?

Comment: Ran this in < 5s where each df had 1 million+ obs, so I think for most practical purposes this is plenty fast!